# When I use redirect_stdout in python 3.11, the terminal width appears to be set to 80. How can I change this value?

Tags: python, argparse

For example, when automatically collating arparse help, I'd ideally like to set a specific width:

```
def parse_help(command_list=... width=168):
    command_list = [] if command_list is ... else command_list

    s = io.StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(s, width=width):
        try:
            do_command([*command_list, '--help'])
        except SystemExit:
            pass

    help_text = s.getvalue()
    print_help(help_text)

    for subcommand in get_subcommands(help_text):
        parse_help([*command_list, subcommand])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333577/explain-lambda-argparse-helpformatterprog-width explains how a `lambda` formatter can be used to explicitly set the `width` of the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argparse`'s [help formatter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d4f83e1e3a19e2f881115f20d58ae6a019ddb48f/Lib/argparse.py#L171) uses [`shutil.get_terminal_size`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.get_terminal_size) to obtain the column size of the terminal connected to stdout, which falls back to 80 characters when stdout is not connected to a terminal.

To override it for child processes that use `argparse` to produce help messages, one easy approach is to set the environment variable `COLUMNS` as mentioned in the documentation of `shutil.get_terminal_size`:

```
import os

os.environ['COLUMNS'] = '168'
s = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(s):
    do_command([*command_list, '--help'])
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/DemandingPoliticalConversion

Comment: That is already in use and is using the terminal width - correct behavior when reporting the help normally. For the collated help, the redirection results in the actual terminal width being ignored and a default width of 80 being used. That is why I was trying to change the 'terminal' width for redirect_stdout's virtual terminal.

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Answer (score 0):

`parser.print_help` calls `parser.format_help`, which calls `parser._get_formatter` to actually create a `Formatter` object.

That creation is performed by `parser.formatter_class(prog=self.prog)`, using the `formatter_class` specificed in the `ArgumentParser` command.

That allows us to use the default formatter class, or specify a subclass, one of the 'raw' ones provided, or other custom.

The default `__init__` is

```
         def __init__(self,
             prog,
             indent_increment=2,
             max_help_position=24,
             width=None):
```

So normally the `prog` gets passed to the formatter, but not the width.  Instead width is deduced from the window etc.

So a around this is to specify something like

```
formatter = lambda prog: argparse.HelpFormatter(prog, width=100)
parser=ArgumentParser(..., formatter_class=formatter)
```

defining a psudo-subclass that provides a custom width.

The idea has been floating around SO for some time, [Explain lambda argparse.HelpFormatter(prog, width)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333577/explain-lambda-argparse-helpformatterprog-width), and may also appear on the old python bug/issues forum.